# VBA issue with VLookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue with my VLookup function as it does not find a value I know is in the range.  The Product variable has to remain a string as I am looking up numbers and mixed numbers with text.  Also my instructor does not allow the use of variants.

```
Sub LookupValue()
Dim Product As String
Dim ErrCheck As Boolean
Dim Quantity As Integer
Dim Discount As Double
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Worksheets("Prices").Range("A2:C21")

ErrCheck = True

'Obtaining VLookup Value
Product = InputBox("Enter the product's code.")

'Error checking
Do Until ErrCheck = False
    If Product = "" Then
        ErrCheck = True
        MsgBox ("Not a valid entry.")
        Product = InputBox("Enter the product's code.")
    ElseIf IsError(Application.VLookup(Product, myRange, 3, False)) Then
        ErrCheck = True
        MsgBox ("The value entered was not found.")
        Product = InputBox("Enter the product's code.")
    Else
        ErrCheck = False
    End If
Loop

'Obtaining Quantity Value
Quantity = InputBox("Enter the quantity ordered.")

'Error checking
Do Until ErrCheck = False
    If IsNumeric(Quantity) = False Then
        ErrCheck = True
        MsgBox ("Not a valid entry.")
        Quantity = InputBox("Enter the quantity ordered.")
            Else
                ErrCheck = False
    End If
Loop

'Obtaining discount rate
If Quantity < 25 Then
    Discount = 0.1
    If Quantity < 50 Then
        Discount = 0.15
        If Quantity < 75 Then
            Discount = 0.2
            If Quantity < 100 Then
                Discount = 0.25
                If Quantity >= 100 Then
                    Discount = 0.3
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

'Filling in cells
Sales.Range("B2") = Product
Sales.Range("B3") = Application.VLookup(Product, myRange, 2, False)
Sales.Range("B4") = Quantity
Sales.Range("B5") = Discount
Sales.Range("B6") = Application.VLookup(Product, myRange, 3, False)
Sales.Range("B7") = Range("B6").Value * Quantity
Sales.Range("B8") = Range("B7").Value * Discount
Sales.Range("B9") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("B7:B8")

End Sub
```

An example of the lookup range is

89044 | Widget | 12.00

Comment: are you sure the value does not contain an extra space or something like this? is the vlookup in Excel returning the right result?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that the two values are identical.  The values being looked up are also in general format.

Comment: give `Application.VLookup(Val(Product), myRange, 3, False)` a try, just to be sure

Comment: This worked! I thought I tried this but apparently I changed something else and didn't try again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data your checking is of type number, however, you provide a string to the VLOOKUP function.

Therefore, instead of `Application.VLookup(Product, myRange, 3, False)`, use

```
Application.VLookup(Val(Product), myRange, 3, False)
```

Comment: This works for the number values; however, when I input another value such as "45-C-33" it's not found.

Comment: I have implemented an isnumeric to go between Val(Product) and just Product. Thanks for the answer.